# Is Exchange ActiveSync enabled by user? device? device type or OS?

Tags: android, email, exchange-server, policy, activesync

Is Exchange ActiveSync enabled by user? device? device type or device OS?

I'm asking because  I'm going to an employer who said they only support Exchange corporate email on Blackberry or iPhone.   I just purchased a Samsung Epic Android phone under Sprint. As far as I now there is no Enterprise email plan for that phone. But it does run ActiveSync.

Why would an employer limit the devices allowed to access email and can they really enforce that?  Is the limitation usually a function of what devices can run Active Sync?

Also, if they do allow my Android, what beyond entering the the user, pw and exchange server do they need to do on my phone? Can they put a policy on my personal phone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definitely depends on your employer. Android phones running Froyo (2.2) do support Exchange ActiveSync. They can put password enforcement policies onto your phone, yes. They may have just not tested it on Android yet, so they won't officially support it yet. You should talk to the IT department, maybe bring in the phone and let them try it out if they've got an open mind for it.

Comment: I'm on 2.1.  I read this.. "Android 2.1+ Along with the update to Android 2.1 comes enhanced Exchange ActiveSync support".  I see an Exchange option when adding accounts.  I tried to configure it to their server with no luck. Do you know if they need to enable my account for active Sync? thanks.

Comment: I don't believe so. I didn't think 2.1 supported Exchange but apparently I'm incorrect. They added a lot of security features to it in 2.2, at least. Honestly, the only experience I have with ActiveSync is with my Hotmail account; as long as you have the right server address, username and password I would think it would work; they may have to enable ActiveSync for your account though. Hope you can get it working!